# Spring data neo4j cypher dialect is not enforced everywhere

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

When upgrading to Neo4j v5.9.0 I tried to enforce the Neo4j v5 dialect as the documentation suggests by creating the following configuration

```kotlin
import org.neo4j.cypherdsl.core.renderer.Dialect
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.neo4j.cypherdsl.core.renderer.Configuration as CypherConfiguration

@Configuration
class Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun cypherDslConfiguration(): CypherConfiguration =
        CypherConfiguration.newConfig().withDialect(Dialect.NEO4J_5).build()
}
```

When checking from spring actuator, the following bean seems to be present

```json
"cypherDslConfiguration": {
  "aliases": [],
  "scope": "singleton",
  "type": "org.neo4j.cypherdsl.core.renderer.Configuration",
  "resource": "class path resource [com/foo/infra/neo4j/Neo4jConfiguration.class]",
  "dependencies": [
    "neo4jConfiguration"
  ]
}
```

and when using repository queries I'm still getting the following warning from all sorts of different queries

```
Neo.ClientNotification.Statement.FeatureDeprecationWarning: This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
    UNWIND $__relationships__ AS relationship WITH relationship MATCH (startNode:`MyNode`) WHERE startNode.entityId = relationship.fromId MATCH (endNode) WHERE id(endNode) = relationship.toId MERGE (startNode)-[relProps:`BELONGS`]->(endNode) RETURN elementId(relProps) AS __elementId__
                                                                                                                                                                       ^
The query used a deprecated function: `id`.
```

Where the `entityId` field on the node is annotated with the `@Id` annotation.

Is there some configuration I'm still missing or is my cypherDslConfiguration bean incorrect?

Relevant versions:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j 3.1.2
- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j 7.1.2
- kotlin 1.9.0

Comment: If you are defining a `@GeneratedValue` `@Id` of type `Long` on the domain class, it will still use the `id` function.

Comment: @meistermeier I'm not defining `@GeneratedValue` and the id's are strings not longs